# How to do exponential calculation with matrix?

Tags: r, calculated-columns, exponential

I want to calculate exponential with a matrix and vector. The matrix is as below

```
 ID     var_0     var_01    var_02   var_03 
 1        1         2        3        4
 2        5         6        7        8
 3        9         10       11       12
 ...
```

and vector is (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)

I want to get the result as below

```
 ID       var_0   var_01     var_02   var_03 
 1        1^0.1     2^0.2    3^0.3    4^0.4
 2        5^0.1     6^0.2    7^0.3    8^0.4
 3        9^0.1     10^0.2   11^0.3    12^0.4
 ...
```

That is, I want to get (ith var)^ith vector for each ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use R's recycling of vectors. Transpose your matrix so that the power calculations are applied in the correct order and then transpose back.

```
(m <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    5    6    7    8
# [3,]    9   10   11   12

p <- 1:4

t(t(m)^p)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]    1    4   27   256
# [2,]    5   36  343  4096
# [3,]    9  100 1331 20736
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `sweep` function. The signature is

```
sweep(x, MARGIN, STATS, FUN)
```

This function iterates over parts of `x` according to how you set `MARGIN`. On each iteration, the current part of `x` and the entire argument `STATS` get passed to `FUN`, which should be a function taking 2 arguments.

Setting `MARGIN` to 1 means `STATS` lines up with the rows of `x` (dimension 1), 2 means `STATS` lines up with the columns of `x` (dimension 2). Other variations are also possible.

So for your particular example, use

```
sweep(your.matrix, 2, your.exponents, `^`)
```

---

**Edit:** Based on @david-arenburg's answer, you probably shouldn't use `sweep`. I had no idea it was so slow!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do (data from @user20650's post)

```
 m^p[col(m)]
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
 #[1,]    1    4   27   256
 #[2,]    5   36  343  4096
 #[3,]    9  100 1331 20736
```

Comment: oh i think it would be - the double transpose wont be fast

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe (using @user20650's data set)

```
m^rep(p, each = nrow(m))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]    1    4   27   256
# [2,]    5   36  343  4096
# [3,]    9  100 1331 20736
```

Another option

```
m ^ matrix(p, nrow(m), ncol(m), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]    1    4   27   256
# [2,]    5   36  343  4096
# [3,]    9  100 1331 20736
```

---

Some benchmarks on a bigger data set. Seems like my two answers and @akruns scales the best

```
n <- 1e6
cols <- 100
m <- matrix(seq_len(n), nrow = n, ncol = cols)
p <- seq_len(cols)

user20650 = function() {t(t(m)^p)}
Nick =  function() {sweep(m, 2, p, `^`)}
akrun = function() {m^p[col(m)]}
David1 = function() {m^rep(p, each = nrow(m))}
David2 = function() {m ^ matrix(p, nrow(m), ncol(m), byrow = TRUE)}

library(microbenchmark)
Res <- microbenchmark(
               user20650() ,
               Nick(),
               akrun(),
               David1(),
               David2() 
)

Res

# Unit: seconds
       # expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# user20650()  9.692392  9.800470  9.878385 10.010198 11.002012   100
#      Nick() 10.487660 10.595750 10.687573 10.896852 14.083319   100
#     akrun()  8.213784  8.316646  8.395962  8.529671  9.325273   100
#    David1()  9.115449  9.219430  9.304380  9.425614 10.445129   100
#    David2()  8.157632  8.275277  8.335884  8.437017  9.348252   100

boxplot(Res)
```

[image]